# How to get information about place shown by marker

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have function which shows cafes near by my localization and marks it as blue marker on map. Is it possible to get information about place marked by mark when I click on it?

After click on Mark, I have to save information about selected place.

My code:
below is function to find cafes near by my localization

```
public void findCafe(View view){
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder( "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
        String locationStr = clatlng.latitude +","+clatlng.longitude ;
        stringBuilder.append( "location="+ locationStr);
        stringBuilder.append( "&radius=").append( PROXIMITY_RADIUS );
        stringBuilder.append( "&type="+"cafe");
        stringBuilder.append("&sensor=true");
        stringBuilder.append( "&key="+getResources().getString( R.string.new_key ));

        String url = stringBuilder.toString();
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(url,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject result) {

                Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: Result= " + result.toString());
                try {
                    parseLocationResult(result);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onErrorResponse: Error= " + error);
                        Log.e(TAG, "onErrorResponse: Error= " + error.getMessage());
                    }
                });

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
    }
```

```
public class AppController extends Application {

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;

    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `OnMarkerClickListener` to listen for click events on the marker as per Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/marker#marker_click_events).

Once you have the place IDs for the places you get through your existing Nearby Search implementation, you can use the [Place Details](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/place-details) service to get information of those places. E.g.:

```
// Define a Place ID.
String placeId = "INSERT_PLACE_ID_HERE";

// Specify the fields to return.
List<Place.Field> placeFields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME);

// Construct a request object, passing the place ID and fields array.
FetchPlaceRequest request = FetchPlaceRequest.newInstance(placeId, placeFields);

placesClient.fetchPlace(request).addOnSuccessListener((response) -> {
    Place place = response.getPlace();
    Log.i(TAG, "Place found: " + place.getName());
}).addOnFailureListener((exception) -> {
    if (exception instanceof ApiException) {
        ApiException apiException = (ApiException) exception;
        int statusCode = apiException.getStatusCode();
        // Handle error with given status code.
        Log.e(TAG, "Place not found: " + exception.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Hope this helps!